# Is there anything that can go wrong when I use static to implement a singleton?

Tags: objective-c, singleton

I'm implementing a singleton class (and lets not get into the discussion if that is wrong or not). I have a method to get the instance of this class, which is lazily initialized:

```
+ (FFDataManager *)sharedDataManager {
  static FFDataManager *dm = nil;
  if (!dm) {
    dm = [[FFDataManager alloc] init];
  }

  return dm;
}
```

Is there anything I should look out for when doing this using `static` (inside of the method) as opposed to creating a global variable? Is there anything that can go wrong, all tutorials on the Internet use a global variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My preferred singleton implementation looks like:

```
+ (MyClass *) sharedInstance {
    static dispatch_once_t predicate = 0;
    __strong static MyClass *shared = nil;

    dispatch_once(&predicate, ^{
        shared = [[self alloc] init];
    });

    return shared;
}
```

Using `dispatch_once` makes sure this is also thread safe. Your code would allocate twice when accessed by multiple threads at the same time.

Comment: Would it not be better to return `id` then if you do subclass you would not have to do a cast? You would need to change `MyClass` to `id` as well.

Comment: That's a possibility as well. I changed from id to explicit class names from my original answer to match the question.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the original question (others have address the best way to do initialization):

> Is there anything I should look out for when doing this using static (inside of the method) as opposed to creating a global variable?

No.

The difference is over *visibility* and not *lifetime*.

- A global's (with or without static) *lifetime* is that of the application execution.
- A global without `static` is *visible* throughout the whole application. From anywhere else it can be referenced by naming it in an `extern` statement.
- A global with `static` is *visible* just in the containing compilation unit (which is typically a single file, but `#import`/`#include` can change that).
- A variable declared within a function/method as `static` is a global which is only *visible* within that function/method.

If you're using a global in just one function what you've done is good - it limits the visibility to just where it is needed while keeping execution-lifetime. Any initializer is run once, just as for file-level globals.

Answer (score -1):

What you create is a static local variable. Static local variables retain their value through successive method invocations. They can only be accessed from within the method which they are defined in. When apps start static local variables are set to 0 once.

So what you do in my opinion is with every call of `sharedDataManager` you declare a new static local variable and set it to `nil`. I don't think that's necessary or even good. And also every time `if (!dm)` checks `dm` it is `nil` because you set dm to nil the line before.

I'd go with the static global approach.

Edit:
Have a look at http://www.johnwordsworth.com/2010/04/iphone-code-snippet-the-singleton-pattern/

Comment: "…with every call of sharedDataManager you declare a new static local variable…" but in the first paragraph you just said that they "retain their value through successive method invocations." Am I missing something here?

Comment: @WTP'-- no you're not missing anything. Sorry drct but this answer is wrong.

Comment: I never said to make it a static local variable. And by the way I just described the way to implement a singleton recommended by Apple. 

`SingletonClass.m
#import "SingletonClass.h"

@implementation SingletonClass

static SingletonClass *sharedInstance = nil;

// Get the shared instance and create it if necessary.
+ (SingletonClass *)sharedInstance {
    if (sharedInstance == nil) {
        sharedInstance = [[super allocWithZone:NULL] init];
    }

    return sharedInstance;
}
...` 

So thanks for the downvotes guys. But maybe you were too quick with it.